# I'm getting DirectXTK errors when compiling the samples

Tags: xbox-live

I'm attempting to build the Xbox Live samples and running into DirectXTK errors.  This happens irrespective of whether I'm using the Creator's Program or ID@Xbox samples.  These are the samples at https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-samples

For example, when opening the Leaderboard sample I see "DirectXTK (unavailable)" in the Solution Explorer.

When trying to build, I get the following output

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Leaderboards, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1611,5): warning : The referenced project '..\..\..\..\Kits\DirectXTK\DirectXTK_Windows10.vcxproj' does not exist.
1>  pch.cpp
1>c:\users\rigu\xsapi\github\test\xbox-live-samples\samples\creatorssdk\leaderboards\uwp\cpp\pch.h(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GamePad.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas on how I can get the sample building & running?

Answer (score 1):

The DirectXTK is a submodule in the Xbox Live samples git repo.  There are two ways to make sure you get DirectXTK.

1. When initially cloning, make sure you use the "--recursive" option.  IE:

   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-samples.git`
2. If you already cloned the samples directory, you can initialize submodules with:

   `git submodule update --init`

   Then you can update them with:

   `git submodule update`